# Concatenate write parameters in C++

Tags: c++

I need to concatenate the parameters in the write function. How would I do this?

Example:  `ofstream write(newFolder concat "/newfile.txt");`

```
mkdir(newFolder);
ofstream write (wantTo "concat here");
write << "Sup mo fo";
write.close();
```

Comment: `std::string` supports `+` operator, did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `newFolder` is a std::string, you can simply use `newFolder + "/newfile.txt"`. You'd have to make sure `newFolder` does not end with a `/` or a `\` though. You may need to use the `c_str()` function on your std::string if you require a char* in your `write` function.

Comment: It would be good to distinguish "`std::string`" from "string literal" or "C-style string". Only `std::string` supports operator `+`.

Answer (score 0):

While using `std::string` is the preferred way, be careful because older versions of the standard library doesn't support an `open` method that takes a `std::string` as argument.

If you get an error in the call to `open` when using `std::string`, then you have to do it in two steps:

```
std::string newFolder = "/path/to/folder";
mkdir(newFolder.c_str(), 0644);  // The 'mkdir'  function wants 'const char *'

// Has to concatenate strings here if your standard library is too old
std::string folderAndFile = newFilder + "/filename";

std::ofstream output(folderAndfile.c_str());
```

Comment: Can you explain the 'const char *' part of the mkdir call?

Comment: @Cjueden The system call `mkdir` is an old C function, and don't know about C++ classes like `std::string`. If you look at the [manual page for `mkdir`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir) you see that the path argument is of type `const char *`, which is returned by [`std::string::c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str).